# Kotlin - How do I substitute a String with elements of Mutable List of Pairs?

Tags: kotlin, encryption, monolithic

I am working on Monoalphabetic Cipher and I have to encrypt a message by substituting it with any other alphabet.

```
fun encrypt(message:String){
//Assume message as ABCD
var encrypt:String = ""

val alphabets = ('A'..'Z').toMutableList() //['A','B','C','D',....]

var shuffAlp = alphabets.shuffled() // Assume shuffled op as ['D','L','N','J',....]

var pair = alphabets.zip(shuffAlp)
println(pair)   // Assume pair as [(A, D), (B, L), (C, N), (D, J), ...] acc to shuffled op

for(m in message){
    for (p in pair){
        if(p.first == m)
            encrypt+=p.second
        }
    }
println(encrypt) //DLNJ according to given pair
}
```

As you can see I have used two for loops to generate my encrypt String. I was wondering if there is an equivalent Lambda function or extensions that would discard two loops?

Comment: If message had repeated characters and zipping allot different character pairs then how would you tackle that, for example if message is `"ABCA"`, then `(A,D)` and `(A,E)` maybe present so what do you want it to replace? with current code it will be `DELNDE`

Comment: the `message` is not being mapped with `shuffAlp`, `alphabets` is being mapped with `shuffAlp`. Once you read Monoalphabetic Cipher this code will make more sense and you might even come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After zipping, use `toMap` so you can look up the encrypted values easily without looping.

You're using `var`s where your variables can be constant `val`s, and `MutableList` as an unnecessary intermediate step.

```
// Assumes message contains only capital letters
fun encrypt (message: String): String {
    val alphabet = 'A'..'Z'
    val cipher = alphabet.zip(alphabet.shuffled()).toMap()
    return message.map { cipher[it] }.joinToString("")
}
```

But if you want a message that you can decrypt later, you need separate functions so you can store the cipher and reuse it. Something like this:

```
fun createCipher(): Map<Char, Char> {
    val alphabet = 'A'..'Z'
    return alphabet.zip(alphabet.shuffled()).toMap()
}

fun encrypt(message: String, cipher: Map<Char, Char>): String {
    return message.map { cipher[it] }.joinToString("")
}

fun decrypt(encrpytedMessage: String, cipher: Map<Char, Char>): String {
    val invertedCipher = cipher.entries.associate { it.value to it.key }
    return encrpytedMessage.map { invertedCipher [it] }.joinToString("")
}
```